# Django: Bad request when sending request using reactJS

Tags: django

I am using django-rest-framework at backend and I am trying to post following data from react frontend.

```
handleSubmit() {
   fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/debt/create',{
       method: 'POST',
       headers: {
           Authorization: `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem('id_token')}`,
           'Content-Type': 'application/json'
       },
       body: JSON.stringify({
           user: '1',
           customer: '9',
           debtKey: 'b1d9ef1b-45ad-4dc5-80cc-95f7994c0aae',
           createduserKey: '0245abb9-2837-4f37-ae02-9be1b88887ef',
           totalDebt: 789,
           receivedAmount: 115,
           description: 'Debt description',
           paymentDate: '01.01.2019'
       }),
   }).then(response => {
       console.log(response);
       return response.json()
   }).then(json => {
       //this.setState({
       //    user:json
       //});
   });
 console.log("Form Sumbmssion");
}
```

But I am getting `"BAD REQUEST"` error. What I am missing? Thanks

Comment: A bad request means the data you are sending from React to Django is not what Django expects. Try to log any validation errors in Django to see which post data is missing or incorrect. It could be something as simple as a missing field or invalid data. You need to post your Django view and possibly models to work it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Authorization` is a key .it should be in `quotes`.

```
headers: {
       'Authorization': `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem('id_token')}`,
       'Content-Type': 'application/json'
   },
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you just need to add "/" to http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/debt/create at the end.
Bad request is often due to that issue only. But why are you using fetch anyway. Please consider using axios if you are using React.js on the frontend. It is identical to fetchAPI, but is lot more flexible.